# Difference between Android BOOT_COMPLETED & category HOME

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, boot

I am trying to solve a start on boot related problem and I noticed many examples of the AndroidManifest.xml which has android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED and some that also have the category of android.intent.category.HOME in there.  Does anyone know what the difference (if any) between the two are?

ie.

```
       <receiver android:name=".MartiniBootBroadCastReciever"
        android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
        <intent-filter>
            <action                   android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>        
    </receiver>
```

versus

```
        <receiver android:name=".MartiniBootBroadCastReciever"
        android:enabled="true" android:exported="false"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Umm, they are not even remotely the same thing. In fact, the only SIMILARITY is that they are both part of an intent filter.

Comment: When does each one exactly get executed?  I guess that is what I'm trying to distinguish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, your first one is wrong. The `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast should not have that category, AFAIK.

Comment: Hmm, I just saw several examples like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635353/is-android-permission-receive-boot-completed-not-required) that had that category along with boot_completed.

Comment: @Dave: Well, apparently it works. It is definitely not necessary.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Can you please kindly help me on my question which is related to Boot Completed Event...Here is the link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118576/getting-resourcenotfoundexception-after-device-rebooted...