# Starting application on boot completed

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, intentfilter

The following is the code I'm using for starting my Application when device is turned on.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("BootReceiver","intent received");

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, ACT_Home.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }

}
```

and in the Manifest (as `<Application>` child):

```
<receiver android:name="host.alarmmanager.BootReceiver">
   <intent-filter >
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The permissions inside the Manifest are the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

This works fine on Android 3.2.2, but if I try the same application on Android 4.0.3 the broadcast receiver does not receive anything. 
Also the first line inside the `onReceive` method is not execeuted. 
Why this happens?

Comment: [Did you start your app at least once manually?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952562/broadcast-receiver-not-working-in-ics-if-the-app-is-not-started-atleast-once)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

This you should use in android manifest

Comment: But why my solution works in Android 3.2.2 without adding this permission?

Comment: Do not exactly know, but if we will look at percentage of android versiones 3.x.x less that 1%. So you can easely forget about it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635353/is-android-permission-receive-boot-completed-not-required

Comment: Ok @Seliv I'm about to try it

Answer (score 2):

Try this, although your code seems fine! The following is working for me.

```
    <!-- Receivers -->
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="host.alarmmanager.BootReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635353/is-android-permission-receive-boot-completed-not-required

Comment: @Joseph82 since it works on some devices, I assume you had the permission in your manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not restarting your phone by selecting restart option from the power menu.

**Android bizarrely has 2 different permissions.**

> 1.Reboot
>
> 2.On boot complete

So,
first power off your phone and then after few seconds power on it again!

Hope it helps! (Y)